# Correct Use of Matcher Groups in Java Regex when using logical OR

Tags: java, regex

I have to parse a string that contains latitude & longitude values. The strings can be in one of two formats:

```
Lat: 33.1234 Lon: -110.1234
Lat, Lon: 33.1234 -110.1234
```

I'm using Pattern & Matcher in Java. The following regex matches either string correctly:

```
Lat, Long:\s*([-\d\.]+)[\,\s]+([-\d\.]+)|Lat:\s*([-\d\.]+)\s*Lon[g]?:\s*([-\d\.]+)
```

However...the matcher has 4 groups. Either the first two groups OR the second two groups have the lat/lon values and the other two are null.

I realize I can just test for null ... but I was curious if there's a way to only have the matcher return two groups containing the lat & lon values regardless of which string format was given?

Comment: For regex, the `|` character is called the *alternation operator*. Perhaps that will help with Google searches.

Comment: Is your second example correct there?  Your regex makes me suspect that you meant for that one to be `Lat, Long: 33.1234, -110.1234`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex matches your two sample cases.

`Lat(?:,\s+Long?)?:\s*([-\d\.]+)(?:\s+|\s*,\s*)(?:Long?:\s+)?([-\d\.]+)`

https://regex101.com/r/D3aBpX/1

```
 Lat                           # Lat label
 (?: , \s+ Long? )?            # optional , Long label
 :                             # colon
 \s*                           # optional space
 ( [-\d\.]+ )                  # (1), lat value
 (?: \s+ | \s* , \s* )         # Seperated by space or comma ( must have one )
 (?: Long?: \s+ )?             # optional Long label and colon
 ( [-\d\.]+ )                  # (2), long value
```

Comment: Slight adjustment on this to accommodate the "," between lat/lon values:
Lat(?:,\s+Long?)?:\s*([-\d\.]+)\s*,?\s*(?:Long?:\s+)?([-\d\.]+)

Comment: @MSquared - I update the answer to reflect this `(?: \s+ | \s* , \s* )` There is a required separator in this case it's space or comma. That's so the first `[-\d\.]+` does not consume all of the value chars. If it were all optional, `\s*,?\s*` would allow no separation and result in a faulty match should there be no separator in error.

Answer (score 0):

You could test to see whether the input is valid and then parse the input separately. It's a little bit slower (two regexes), but it means you'll have two predictable capture groups.

So you can do something like: (Obviously, feel free to re-use the patterns :) ):

```
if (Pattern.compile("Lat[,:].*Long?:.*").matcher(inputString).matches()) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*([-\d\.]+)\b.*([-\d\.]+).*")
        .matcher(inputString);
    if (m.matches()) {
        // m.group(1) is always lat, and m.group(2) is always lon
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options I can think of (I have made the same assumption that Matthew made about your second input being wrong).

---

Make the regex more lenient and use named groups.  I think the following should work for that (although I can't say I find this too readable):

```
"Lat[:,](?:\\s+Long:)?\\s+(?<lat>[\\-\\+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)(?:\\,)?(?:\\sLong?:)?\\s+(?<long>[\\-\\+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)"
```

---

Use a `Scanner` to check for the values instead of regex.  Something along the lines of:

```
final double latitude, longitude;
try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input)) {

    while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) scanner.next();
    latitude = scanner.nextDouble();

    while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) scanner.next();
    longitude = scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

Unfortunately this does no validation that the input meets expectations, beyond having at least two parsable doubles in it (that should be added).  It is however (to me at least) a lot more readable at a glance.